# Fullcalendar custom view "vertical resource view" not working correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using fullcalendar 4 on angular and I need to use a custom view based on this demo :
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/vertical-resource-custom-demo

My view needs to be on 5 days (monday to friday) and for just 1 resource. I edited the demo to do what i wanted but the calendar isn't displaying the 5 days everytime. For example this week, it's only display from Today to Friday and Friday to Tuesday the previous week.

I've done a codepen of my problem and the view i created:

```
  resourceTimeGridFiveDay: {
    type: "resourceTimeGrid",
    duration: { days: 5 },
    buttonText: "5 days"
  }
```

https://codepen.io/Archelite/pen/QWKQyZR

How can i force the calendar to show always the 5 days (Monday to Friday)?

Comment: Just use the normal week view and set the "weekends" setting to false. Check the documentation for details.

Comment: ok but is it possible to edit the title of the calendar by adding the name of the resource? With the normal week view, i would have a title like '' 30 dec -3 jan - Room A"

Comment: It already shows the resource names - demo: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/vertical-resource-custom-demo . It makes no sense to add the resource name to the _title_, because there might be more than one resource. Therefore they are shown above the columns which belong to that resource, just like in that demo.

Comment: Yes, i agree on that. But in order to show 5 days (monday to friday) i must use the normal week view which doesn't show the resource name. That's why i wanted to use a custom vertical resource view.

Comment: A 5-day view is trivial: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/JjRppYy?editors=001  by using the "week" view and hiding the weekends. And resource names are shown. I've no idea what you think the problem is. I've added it as a full answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to make a 5-day view of Monday-Friday - just use the normal "week" setting of the vertical resuorce view, and set the option to hide weekends:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'resourceTimeGrid' ],
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    defaultView: 'resourceTimeGridWeek', //USE NORMAL VERTICAL RESOURCE WEEK VIEW
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimeGridWeek'
    },
    resources: [
      { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
      { id: 'b', title: 'Room B' }
    ],
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?with-resources=2',
    weekends: false //HIDE WEEKENDS
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/JjRppYy?editors=001

Documentation of the "weekends" setting: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/weekends

Comment: Thanks, indeed, that's what i need. The fact is I didn't know "resourceTimeGridWeek" exists, I searched in the Documentation but only found "resourceTimeGridDay" (now i think about it it's logical to have a week view too). Where is it written ?

Comment: Maybe it's not written directly, but since it's made clear that it's just a resource-enabled variation of the basic timeGrid view, then you can assume that there's a "week" view for it just as mentioned in the standard [timeGrid documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/timegrid-view). I guess it could be a little clearer, but that's maybe something you can raise an issue with the fullCalendar developers about, if it bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you removed week-end if you change   `duration: { days: 5 }` to `duration: { days: 7 }` it will works.
And if you want to start your calendar to monday just change `initialView: 'timeGridWeek'`

Comment: Indeed, it shows 5 days every time but now it shows from Wednesday (because of today) to Tuesday and adding firstDay: 0 don't work. What is missing ?

Comment: I think you have to change your initialview

Comment: @antoineso initialView is for fullCalendar 5, but this question is tagged as fullCalendar 4

Comment: @ADyson you're right but  intialview is set in the codepen link in the question

Comment: @antoineso I think for some reason OP gave us a demo which doesn't match everything else that's tagged or mentioned in the question.